# Changing width of GridLayout elements

Tags: java, swing

I want to change each buttons width but it's not working (i'am new in swing)
[image]

```
    Panel = new JPanel();
    gl = new GridLayout(2, 1);
    Panel.setLayout(gl);
    add(Panel, BorderLayout.EAST);

    Up= new JButton("Btn1");
    Up.addActionListener(this);
    Up.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,150));
    Panel.add(Up);

    Down = new JButton("Btn2");
    Down.addActionListener(this);
    Down.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,300));
    Panel.add(Down);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this case I would use the [GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html). This can be adapted very well with the [GridBagConstraints](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html).

In your case the `weighty` parameter would be responsible for controlling the height of the button in the panel. This is given as a percentage.

The code would look like this:

```
panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
add(panel, BorderLayout.EAST);

up = new JButton("Btn1");
up.addActionListener(this);
up.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 150));
panel.add(up, new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 100, 33, GridBagConstraints.NORTH, GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL, new Insets(0,0,0,0), 0,0));

down = new JButton("Btn2");
down.addActionListener(this);
down.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 300));
panel.add(down, new GridBagConstraints(0, 1, 1, 1, 100, 66, GridBagConstraints.NORTH, GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL, new Insets(0,0,0,0), 0,0));
```

The result looks like this:

[image: Result]

Comment: Since `setPreferredSize` was used in both the question & answer, I'll direct this comment to both of you. See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.) My main objection to using it is that it is a guess, & is 'fragile' in that if a later programmer changes the font size or text of the button, or the [margin](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setMargin(java.awt.Insets)) around it, it might break. Best to adjust those factors then `pack()`.

Answer (score 0):

This question already has an accepted answer, but just wanted to put some 'tweaks' into an answer.

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class BigWideButtons {

    private JComponent ui = null;
    static int upCodepoint = 9206; // upward triangle
    static int downCodepoint = 9207; // downward triangle
    Insets insets = new Insets(0, 75, 0, 75); // wide insets
    Font font = getCompatibleFont().deriveFont(120f); // big font

    BigWideButtons() {
        initUI();
    }

    public void initUI() {
        if (ui!=null) return;

        ui = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 10, 10));
        ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4,4,4,4));
        addButton(upCodepoint);
        addButton(downCodepoint);
    }

    private void addButton(int codepoint) {
        JButton b = new JButton(new String(Character.toChars(codepoint)));
        b.setFont(font);
        b.setMargin(insets);
        ui.add(b);
    }

    private static Font getCompatibleFont() {
        Font[] fonts = GraphicsEnvironment.
                getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAllFonts();
        for (Font font : fonts) {
            if (font.canDisplay(upCodepoint) && 
                    font.canDisplay(downCodepoint)) {
                System.out.println("Font: " + font.getFamily());
                return font;
            }
        }
        return null; // No installed font supports these characters! 
    }

    public JComponent getUI() {
        return ui;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = () -> {
            BigWideButtons o = new BigWideButtons();

            JFrame f = new JFrame(o.getClass().getSimpleName());
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

            f.setContentPane(o.getUI());
            f.pack();
            f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());

            f.setVisible(true);
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

This answer:

1. Uses a `GridLayout`, as seen in the question.
2. Avoids the need to guess a required size - it simply makes the font and button margin large, then packs the frame to fit them.
3. Given the meaning of the buttons 'up & down' it uses triangles pointing in those directions, as available in the Unicode character set.
4. But fonts do not typically have glyphs for *every* Unicode character (the character set is *huge*), so it adds a method which finds a font (the first available) which supports those glyphs. Here it uses "Segoe UI Symbol".